# How to connect to the Gmail API in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

How can I establish a connection to the Gmail API using Ballerina? I intend to utilize the `ballerinax/googleapis.gmail` connector. What are the initial steps, and what types of credentials are necessary?

Answer (score 0):

To initiate a connection to the Google Gmail API within a Ballerina application, refer to [the set up guide](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerinax/googleapis.gmail/4.0.0#set-up-gmail-api) available on [the Ballerina Central website](https://central.ballerina.io/). This comprehensive guide provides step-by-step instructions on configuring the connector and acquiring the requisite credentials. Additionally, the page includes [samples](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerinax/googleapis.gmail/4.0.0#samples) for a quick start.(https://central.ballerina.io/ballerinax/googleapis.gmail/4.0.0#samples) to get a quick start.